# How to add onClick on image.asset in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using three images on clicking which will navigate to other page so how should I use onClick on these images? My code is below:

```
Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                child: Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg',
                    width: 110.0, height: 110.0),
              )),
              Text(
                'Tickets',
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                child: Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg',
                    width: 110.0, height: 110.0),
              )),
              Text(
                'Buy Tickets',
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    child: Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg',
                        width: 110.0, height: 110.0),
                  )),
              Text(
                'Prizes',
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Expected : Adding an onClick on images
I used `GestureDetector` but it is throwing error so I need to know what I should use and how.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
Material(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              child: Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg',
                  width: 110.0, height: 110.0),
            ),
        ),
    )
```

Comment: This worked by clicking on image I am getting the output but a small issue is there, the image is having a grey color border on top and bottom which makes the image seem to be upon that background which I don't need.

Comment: Any idea Why this is so?

Answer (score 65):

I read other answers and found that you were having issues with border, try this solution.

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {}, // Image tapped
  child: Image.asset(
    'assets/cat.jpg',
    fit: BoxFit.cover, // Fixes border issues
    width: 110.0,
    height: 110.0,
  ),
)
```

*If you want splash effects, then use `Ink.image` or `Ink` with `decoration`.*

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: () {}, // Image tapped
  splashColor: Colors.white10, // Splash color over image
  child: Ink.image(
    fit: BoxFit.cover, // Fixes border issues
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    image: AssetImage(
      'assets/cat.jpg,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use InkWell as show by @Murat Aslan.

And you can also use `GestureDetector` as shown below.

```
Material(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Container(
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            child: Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg',
                width: 110.0, height: 110.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: yeah it is working using both gesture detector as well as inkwell but there is a problem: In the output, I am getting a grey colored border on top and bottom of the images any idea why this is so?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the grey border.

Comment: this is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/13kWSAUe4h2ipvUgCPK5IslyO2WNWt7pQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think this problem is related to the height of you Container()

Comment: I don't think so because when I am changing the height width set then, as a result, the size of the image changes. See my code above I am providing height and wifth to images not container.

Comment: Well, i cant really find the fault in the code. Try removing the Column() from Expanded().

Comment: It is showing error after removing that btw thanks so much.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative is to use a `FlatButton` with an `Image` as a child:

```
FlatButton(
    onPressed: () {
      print('I got clicked');
    },
    child: Image.asset('images/ball1.png'),
  ),
```

Comment: FlatButton is deprecated, TextButton should work instead

Answer (score 3):

To render a material splash during tap on image, use `Ink.image`

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Ink.image(
    image: AssetImage('assets/cat.jpg'),
    // fit: BoxFit.cover,
    width: 110,
    height: 110,
  ),
)
```